# Come si chiama questo gesto italiano?

Tags: word-choice, single-words

1. Posiziona la mano come per fare il gesto "OK" (emoji , U+1F44C)
2. modificalo un po' in maniera da avere l'unghia dell'indice a contatto col polpastrello del pollice
3. spingi più forte l'indice contro il pollice nel punto di contatto
4. rilascia improvvisamente il contatto, facendo scattare e distendere l'indice.

Se fai questo gesto colpendo qualcuno con l'indice... puoi fargli anche relativamente male. Sicuramente lo fai arrabbiare.

Io da piccolo lo usavo per spingere le biglie da spiaggia, così:

[image]

**Ma come si chiama questo gesto? C'è un nome in italiano?**

---

Ho chiesto a ChatGPT, il quale mi ha risposto

> Il gesto descritto è chiamato "snap" o "finger snap" in inglese. In italiano, potrebbe essere descritto come "schioccare le dita" o "fare lo schiocco delle dita".

Tuttavia, cercando su internet, [mi sembra si tratti di un gesto diverso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_snapping), quindi anche la traduzione di quello in italiano non sarebbe ciò che cerco.

Comment: Il gesto per schioccare le dita è diverso. Ai miei tempi, non c'era un termine per indicare la mossa; al massimo, dicevamo "muovere la biglia".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sì, come spesso accade ChatGPT vaneggia: “fare lo schiocco delle dita” è un'invenzione presumibilmente dovuta a ritraduzioni varie e “schioccare le dita” significa “Far scattare rumorosamente l’indice o il me­dio con il pollice producendo un suono caratteri­stico, allo scopo di richiamare l’attenzione” ([GDLI](https://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/17?seq=1030)).

Temo che il gesto che dici non abbia un nome panitaliano, ma solo nomi locali. Da romano, per me è normale chiamarlo ***schicchera***, e vedo che il GDLI conferma (sia il senso, sia il fatto che è una voce romanesca):

> **Schicchera**,  sf.  Dial.  Rapido  movimento  del­l’indice  o  del
> medio  che,  liberatosi  dalla  pressione del  pollice,  colpisce
> qualcosa,  in  partic.  un  piccolo oggetto per allontanarlo.
>
> *Pasolini*, 3-103: Strinse tra le dita il mozzone e, con una schicchera, lo fece
> volare via, sul marciapiede.
>
> = Voce roman., di origine espressiva.

([Fonte](https://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/17?seq=1008))

Una definizione analoga (insieme ad altre accezioni del termine) è data nel recente *Vocabolario del romanesco contemporaneo* di D'Achille e Giovanardi. Se esistesse un termine italiano standard, presumibilmente sarebbe stato usato in queste definizioni, anziché descrivere il gesto per esteso.

(Altri dizionari considerano “schicchera” un altro modo per indicare il gesto di schioccare le dita, ma personalmente concordo più con il GDLI.)

Comment: _Schicchera_ lo ricordavo anche io, ma [questra voce](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/schiccherare2/) mi ha fatto pensare di ricordare male. Grazie!

Comment: Riguardo ChatGPT, lungi da me considerarlo una vera intelligenza. Però non è male per cercare ciò che è già noto. Se un termine fosse esistito, immagino l'avrebbe trovato, con qualche aiuto.

Comment: Segnalo questa pagina della federazione ciclotappo in cui sono elencati abbastanza nomi regionali del gesto. https://www.facebook.com/FIGCT/posts/schioccadito-sclicche-ammuttare-ziccaddata-ziccardata-santillo-pinghella-pingell/10161962086300319/, qui ancora meglio https://www.ciclotappo.it/index.php/gioco/tapponomastica

Comment: Però credo sia specifico del gioco con i tappi, io sono di Napoli e mai sentito *santillo* per un colpo. Ai miei tempi, mai sentito un nome per il gesto, tranne il romano *schicchera*, ma perché frequentavo anche ragazzini romani.